# How to improve Get method performace which reads data from hazelcast?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have following controller:

```
@GetMapping("/v1/quotes")
public List<MyQuote> getQuotes() {
    return hazelcastMap.values().stream()
            .map(r -> new Quote(r))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And it takes approximately 330 ms but I have requirement to improve it to execute request in 100 ms or faster.

Any ideas how to improve performance?

Comment: Does running the code through a profiler show where the majority of the time is spent? Do repeated runs yield improved performance (is Hazelcast maybe bringing the data node-local rather than having to fetch it from a remote source during the first invocation - sorry, have no idea about Hazelcast specifically)? Is the Quote constructor which takes the 'r' parameter doing anything computationally expensive?

Comment: @Not a JD, Quote constructor  is very lightweight

Comment: @Not a JD 330 ms  is summarized result during performace testing

Comment: If you don't have something like JProfiler or YourKit on hand, try running several invocations through a VisualVM session and see where the majority of time is spent.

Comment: @gstackoverflow, how many data you have in that Hazelcast map, both # or records & total data size? Also, is this an embedded & client/server deployment? Can you give a bit of information about deployment. # of nodes, network speed etc?

Comment: What is type of `r` and how is it serialized?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally accepted that streams are a bit less efficient than the old-school way with iterators and/or loops.  But you are unlikely to get a 300+% improvement from that.  You might get a 10 or 20% improvement ... if you were transforming a regular in-memory `Map`.  For a Hazelcast `IMap`, the overheads of using streams versus optimal code will be insignificant.

(You should be able to verify this with profiling and careful benchmarking specific to your application.)

---

I think you are going to have to address this in your system design, or possibly by Hazelcast tuning.

Some of the performance problems with what you are currently doing are implied by the `IMap` javadoc:

> `Collection<V> values()`
>
> Returns a collection clone of the values contained in this map.
>
> Warning: The collection is NOT backed by the map, so changes to the map are NOT reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.
>
> This method is always executed by a distributed query, so it may throw a QueryResultSizeExceededException if GroupProperty.QUERY_RESULT_SIZE_LIMIT is configured.

The issues are:

- When you call `values()`, the `IMap` implementation it is creating a copy of the map's values.  You are then streaming from that copy rather than directly from the `IMap`.
- The `values()` operation is performing a distributed query.  I suspect that this is unavoidable.  Either way, this is likely to be the most expensive part of what you are doing.

Comment: I read https://hazelcast.com/for-faster-hazelcast-queries/ what do you think setOptimizeQuery might help?

Comment: It could do.  It is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

What serialization are you using?  All of the data will need to be serialized, and this can have a significant performance impact.  Java serialization is typically the worst in terms of both space and time. IdentifiedDataSerializable is generally the best performing.